# What do I do if I need more than one text index in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, database-indexes

My collection named `Messages` in MongoDB has lots of messages with message content and metadata. Each message has a `Sender` and `Recipient` id, in format of `UUID`, which is in turn a `string`. There are use cases where I need to query both `Sender` and `Recipient` with the same `UUID`, or only `Sender` or only `Recipient` with a `UUID`, or both with different `UUID`s.

I created a text index for the first case which works quite good but I need to search efficiently in other cases as well. What would you suggest? What should I tweak/change? I cannot define any other text index in the same collection because there is a limitation regarding number of text indexes in MongoDB as of now.

Note: I first didn't know about text indexes and tried to create regular indexes, but they are simply not used at all by queries and even if I force them to be used, queries still scan all documents which is useless.

Comment: You don't need text index here at all. It's for full text search. You need a regular index.

Comment: regular indexes are not utilized when querying according to the execution analyses.

Comment: That sounds unlikely. Maybe set up a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: I tried but cannot create index strangely. https://mongoplayground.net/p/OnjLE72UMmr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the playground, you need to use [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-index-on-an-embedded-field) to create index.

That was the reason it didn't use the index.

```
db.Message.createIndex({
  "Sender._id": 1
})
```

You can have another index on `Recipient._id` also. Based on your query, it will use the index.

I mean when you have two separate indices i.e one on `Sender_id`, another on `Recipient._id` and when you query, the respective index will be used.

And your use case is not full text search, so do not use text index for this.

Comment: Sorry but I still cannot create index. https://mongoplayground.net/p/xgVPLSTiSh_

Comment: It seems that there's special syntax for creating collection with indexes on mongoplayground. See the "template" dropdown in the top bar. @schlingel

Comment: Oh well, never mind. Looks like you can't do both your own data and indexes on mongoplayground.

Comment: no no, I used the special syntax and created the index but execution plan still says that it used "collspan": https://mongoplayground.net/p/KGD8CGr1pkc

Comment: Can you share how did you create index in playground?

Comment: @schlingel: your query was wrong. Should be like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/As896fwWXM8). I tried to change your index definition too, but mongoplayground still doesn't seem to create the right indexes (maybe it only can create text indexes? :shrug:). It worked on my localhost (execution plan shows IXSCAN)

Comment: yes apparently for mongodb it is different if I specify x.y or x: { y }.

Comment: @Gibbs, the solution was that I had to create two separate standard indexes rather than one compound index. After this, queries started to do FETCH instead of COLLSCAN. So I used this command `db.Message.createIndexes( [{ "Sender._id": 1}, {"Recipient._id":1 }] )`. If you perhaps make this explicit in the answer, I would happily mark your answer as solution.

Comment: Sure, I meant the same by saying `you can have another index` - I 'll edit further